External monitor through the Display Port
PC: DEll All In One, Windows 11
When I connect a monitor to the Display Port, it changes my Display Settings: Display port Monitor to 1 and the All in One Display as 2. It can not be changed.  It is not the same when I connect to the HDMI output. It works OK. But in my working configuration I use 2 external monitors (Display Port and HDMI) and I need that the All in One stays as Display 1 .
This dindn't happend before with my HP All in One with Windows 10

Aren't you able to move the monitors around?

Settings > System > Display > select the all in one (display 2) > Make this my main display? The actual display number doesn't do anything
